# adjust sampling rate in apollo-server v3

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

It looks like the `reportTiming` option is removed in Apollo Server v3 (introduced in [this PR](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/pull/3918)). We were using it to adjust the sampling rate reporting (now that has ben refactored into its own plugin, `ApolloServerPluginUsageReporting` plugin), but I could not find the old `reportTiming` option there.

So I wonder what are the options of adjusting the sampling rate in the Apollo Server v3 land.

Answer (score 0):

In Apollo Server v3, it can be replaced with [includeRequest](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/plugin/usage-reporting/#includerequest) in `ApolloServerPluginUsageReporting`.